# record/replay debugging i7-3610qm

Tags: debugging, record, vmware-workstation, replay

I am running VMWare 7 + Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 ultimate x64 as a host and Windows XP SP3 32bit as a guest on i7-3610qm. But when attempt to run record/replay function VMWare says that I have unsupported processor, but in the VMWare manual there is said that record/replay should be working on Intel pentium 4 and newer.

I was thinking of changing some settings in BIOS but which ones? Any ideas? Or alternative VM software with function record/replay?